Redirect external website assets to local files
I'm trying to redirect requests from my hosted index.html file that reference external JavaScript and CSS assets to local JS/CSS files on my server. I.e. here my index.html is requesting script.js from foobar.com:
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://foobar.com/foo/scripts/script.js"></script>

and my index.html is not hosted on foobar.com.
I want index.html to request my local /js/script.js instead (without touching the html file).
I've tried in .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect external JavaScript requests to local files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/scripts/script\.js [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /js/$1 [L]

but it doesn't seem to work, index.html is still trying to access the script.js from https://foobar.com
Technically, these requests are not to my server, so is it even possible to catch them? Even though they are coming from index.html that is hosted on my server...

"coming from index.html that is hosted on my server" - the request is coming from the client/browser that has downloaded the index.html file. Taking a step backwards... what is the purpose of this? Is "my server" also hosted "locally" and this is for local development on your PC/LAN? In which case you could indeed force requests to foobar.com to be handled "locally" instead.

@MrWhite The purpose is that I'm creating a mirror of a large website, but the downloaded HTML files still reference to absolute links on the original domain. And there are too many of them to manually update the asset links. Automated script to replace all asset links to relative paths is probably the only viable solution. I don't want it to be exclusively local, no.


Technically, these requests are not to my server, so is it even possible to catch them? Even though they are coming from index.html that is hosted on my server...

No. They never hit your server. What you can do is use mod_substitute to replace strings in the content you send. Note that this will create not insignificant additional load on the server, as it has to actually match and perform substitutions.
